# Only commutators solve this functional equation

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-equations

I need to prove that the only linear transformations $f\colon  M_{n\times n}\rightarrow M_{n\times n}$that solve the functional equation in $\mathcal{L}(M_{n\times n})$
$$f(XY)=f(X)Y+Xf(Y)$$ are the commutators. That is, I have to show that for every linear solution $f$ there exists a matrix $A$ such that $f(X)=[A,X]$ for all $X$. Bearing in mind that every commutator satisfies the equation, I have tried to solve this studying the sets $V_A=\{X\in M_{n \times n}\colon f(X)=[A,X]\}$, where $A\in \ker f$, which happen to be subalgebras that are stable under $f$ and include inverses. Specifically, I have been looking for a maximality argument that leads me to conclude that some of these $V_A$ must be all of $M_{n\times n}$. So far, I have not been able to exploit the finite dimension of $M_{n\times n}$. This problem appears as an exercise at the end of an introductory chapter on matrices and finite dimensional vector spaces in Katsumi Nomizu's *Fundamentals of Linear Algebra*, so little else beyond the rank-nullity theorem is assumed.

Comment: So $f$ is a derivation of the ring $M_n(K)$. Because the ring is simple, $f$ is an inner derivation, i.e., of the form $f(X)=[A,X]$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every Derivation of $M_n (\mathbb{R})$ are inner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387177/every-derivation-of-m-n-mathbbr-are-inner)

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is clearly a very useful link, but given the context in the question (specifically "little else beyond the rank-nullity theorem is assumed"), a more elementary solution would be appropriate. I don't think is a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @TheoBendit I am not sure if such an elementary solution only using little more than rank-nullity is so helpful. It could be very long. I think the natural (and standard) solution is to use either Lie algebra theory or ring theory. In this sense, this is a duplicate for me. But I admit, one may have a different opinion here (or come up with a short and very elementary solution avoiding Lie algebras or simple rings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an elementary proof. Denote the underlying field by $\mathbb F$. Pick two vectors $u,v\in\mathbb F^n$ such that $u^Tv=I_1$, the $1\times1$ identity matrix. Since $f$ is linear, so are the mappings $x\mapsto f(xu^T)v\in\mathbb F^n$ and $y\mapsto u^Tf(vy^T)\in\mathbb F^{1\times n}$. Hence there exist two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $f(xu^T)v=Ax$ and $u^Tf(vy^T)=y^TB$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb F^n$. It follows that
\begin{aligned}
f(xy^T)
&=f\left(x(u^Tv)y^T\right)\\
&=f\left((xu^T)(vy^T)\right)\\
&=f(xu^T)vy^T+xu^Tf(vy^T)\\
&=Axy^T+xy^TB.\\
\end{aligned}
Since $M_n(\mathbb F)$ is spanned by the set of all rank-one matrices, the above gives $f(X)=AX+XB$ for all matrices $X$. However, as $f(I)=f(I^2)=f(I)I+If(I)=2f(I)$, we must have $f(I)=0$. Hence $A+B=0$ and $f(X)=AX+XB=[A,X]$.

Comment: Formally, $u^T v$ is not a scalar, so the equality $f(xy^T)=u^T vf(xy^T)$ is problematic, though not fatal. Anyway, $f(xy^T)=f(x(u^T v)y^T)$ is absolutely transparent.